# Using arcpy.gp.Int_sa in ArcMap gives Error 000824 tool is not licensed?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, error-000824

My Arcpy code is not working in ArcMap 10.1 because an error with the last line:

> Error 000824: The tool is not licensed.

I have all my extensions turned on, so I don't know why I would be getting this error. It seems I only need to import arcpy.sa.

Did I do this correctly, or are there other modules that should be imported for this code to work?

```
import arcpy, os, string, glob, sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\VMshared\small_example_valley8\SD2part"
outFolder = r"C:/VMshared/small_example_valley8/SDpartINT/INT"

for rasterFile in arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif"):
    oName, oExt = os.path.splitext(rasterFile + ".tif")
    outRaster = os.path.join(outFolder, oName + ".tif") 
    arcpy.gp.Int_sa(rasterFile,outRaster)
```

Comment: If you are running the tool outside of ArcGIS session, you need to check out the license: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p600000016000000

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

Comment: As an aside, it's better to use the spatial analyst "map algebra" syntax instead of the undocumented `arcpy.gp`. i.e. `outRaster = Int(Raster(rasterFile))` then `outRaster.save(os.path.join(outFolder, oName + ".tif"))` as that lets you combine multiple steps at once, i.e `outRaster = Con(IsNull(inraster), FocalStatistics(inraster))` similar to the syntax you would use in the raster calculator which is not meant to be used in scripting.

Comment: Geoprocessing error codes are documented, for 000824 see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000013000824

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running the tool outside of ArcGIS session, in Python (or when in the Python window and the extension has not already been enabled), you will need to [check out an ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension license](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p600000016000000) before running a tool.

You do it with:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```